# Trim partial link in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove the start of a link in jQuery. I have tried to inject the following function but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $('link-active').each(function() {
     $(this).attr('href').remove('http://www.linkplus.com/xQWE=');
     });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<td class="block">
<a class="link-active" 
href="http://www.linkplus.com/xQWE=http://www.example.com">Get</a>
</td>
```

Comment: If you know, what value you want to have for href, then set the value for href new instead of trying to remove part from the old value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're trying to search for classes, make use of dot (.), `$('link-active')` should be `$('.link-active')`.
About [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/): this one will remove one element of the DOM; not applicable in this case.

Solution: You will need to use [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr) to return AND update the `href` attribute of your tag, [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method should help.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.link-active').each(function() {
    let href = $(this).attr('href'); //returns href value
    let removableUrl = 'http://www.linkplus.com/xQWE=';
    href = href.replace(removableUrl, ''); //replace the url you don't want with ''
    $(this).attr('href', href); //update href value
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="block">
<a class="link-active" 
href="http://www.linkplus.com/xQWE=http://www.example.com">Get</a>
</td>
```

**Note:** There's other methods to separate the url you don't want (if the url stay in the same format), check for: 
*[.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring): `href = href.substring(removableUrl.length);`*
*[.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split): `href = href.split('=')[1];`*
*.replace() with regex: `href = href.replace(/.*\=/,'');`*

Comment: That works great. If the value changed from zRZl= to kRQA= would I have to use the .replace() method and use some regex on it?

Comment: See the last example? The regex will remove everything before the `=` (including it). :)

Comment: The link id has changed

http://linkplus.net/fXYB=https://file.host/ztPM?dl=PPAbGDpk

Is it possible to strip out the first link even when the ID (fXYB) changes?

Answer (score 0):

Amend `$('link-active')` to `$('.link-active')`.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is While representing a class in jQuery try using dot notation..

```
$(function() {
  $('.link-active').each(function() {
     $(this).attr('href').remove('http://www.linkplus.com/xQWE=');
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's convenient to use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) method like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.link-active').attr('href', function(i, href) {
    return href.replace('http://www.linkplus.com/xQWE=', '');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="link-active" href="http://www.linkplus.com/xQWE=http://www.example.com">Get</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code on line 3 to

```
$(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('http://www.linkplus.com/xQWE=', ''));
```

Full code should be

```
$(function() {
  $('link-active').each(function() {
     $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('http://www.linkplus.com/xQWE=', ''));
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`remove` is not being used correctly here, as that method is meant to remove elements from the DOM and accepts a selector string as its argument.

Try something like this instead:

```
$(function() {
  $('.link-active').each(function() {
     var href = $(this).attr('href');
     var strToReplace = 'http://www.linkplus.com/xQWE=';
     $(this).attr('href', href.replace(strToReplace, ""));
  });
});
```

Above we use `replace` to replace the start of the link with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the string, replace it and then set it again.

Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('link-active').each(function() {
    replacement = 'http://www.linkplus.com/xQWE=';
    url = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', url.replace(replacement, ''));
    });
});
```